# all time conserv same bytes in python

Tags: python

I wouldlike to have same digit/bytes all time (8 bytes)

Example : My first number have 5 decimals after comma : 95.12345 so 8 bytes
          If this number is now 100.12345, I have got 9 bytes. Is it possible to delete the last number to conserv all time 8 bytes like this :

```
         100.12345 ===> 100.1234
         1000.1234 ===> 1000.123
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: What becomes  of `1000000000.12345`?

Comment: ha ha my example is about frequency between 50 and 5000. It's enough for me :)

Comment: `>>> sys.getsizeof(1000.1234) => 24` all you numbers are 24 bytes long in python.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = 95.12345
print(str(x)[:8])
```

> 95.12345

and, to avoid problem with too short strings, you might do:

```
x = 1.00
print("{:0>8s}".format(str(x)[:8]))
```

> 000001.0

Comment: if I want to do the same with tab ?

Answer (score 0):

```
d = 100.12345
print(d, str(d)[:8], sep=' => ')
```

> 100.12345 => 100.1234

But 1 digit is not 1 byte, it's true only for string.

Comment: if i want to use sep directly on this function : client_sock.send(str(freq)[:8]) ?

Comment: data transfer type must be bytes. Use: str(freq)[:11].encde('utf-8')